# Shuffling an array returns TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

I am working on my NN model, and I want to analyze the permutation importance of the inputs. I saw a tutorial to calculate the variable importance from this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-importance-with-neural-network-346eb6205743). The author provides his notebook which you can see [here](https://github.com/cerlymarco/MEDIUM_NoteBook/blob/master/NeuralNet_FeatureImportance/NeuralNet_FeatImportance.ipynb). I only copy the function needed and score computation, but it returns `TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key`

I provide you my full code below:

```py
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
datafreq = pd.read_csv('DATA_FREQ.csv', sep=';')
datatemp = pd.read_csv('DATA_071020.csv', sep=';')
datadiff = pd.read_csv('DATA_DIFFTEMP.csv', sep=';')
y = datadiff.iloc[1:, 4]
y = y.values.reshape(-1, 1)
X1 = datafreq.iloc[:2386, 2:6]
X2 = datatemp.iloc[:2386, 2:6]
X = pd.concat([X1,X2], axis=1)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import MaxAbsScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X = sc.fit_transform(X)
transformer = MaxAbsScaler().fit(y)
y = transformer.transform(y)

# Training and test data split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1, random_state = 0)

# Making the ANN
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout

# Initializing ANN
classifier = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer with dropout
classifier.add(Dense(units = 8, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'tanh', input_dim = 8))
classifier.add(Dropout(rate = 0.1))

# Adding the second hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 4, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'tanh'))
classifier.add(Dropout(rate = 0.1))

# Adding the final layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'tanh'))

# Compiling the ANN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])

# Fitting the ANN to the training set
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 1000)

# Predicting the test dataset results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_ovr = classifier.predict(X)

# Scale back the output
y_ovr = transformer.inverse_transform(y_ovr)

# Making an array to compile the prediction to accumulative temperature
datatemp = datatemp.values
x = []
y_cum = []
y_cumpred = [36]
for i in range(0, 2386):
    x.append([i])
    y_cum.append(datatemp[i, 4])
for i in range(0, 2385):
    y_cumpred.append(y_cumpred[i] + y_ovr[i])
    
# Plotting the graph
plt.plot(x, y_cum, label = "Actual")
plt.plot(x, y_cumpred, label = "ANN Prediction")
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Combustion Temperature')
plt.title('Actual vs ANN')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# R2 score
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
print(r2_score(y_cum, y_cumpred))

# Permutation importance calculation
# Define new function reverse_target
def reverse_target(pred, mean, std): 
    return np.asarray(pred*std + mean)

# Importing new libraries and random seed
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
import random
import os
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(33)
np.random.seed(33)
random.seed(33)

# Converting X_test to dataframe
X_test = pd.DataFrame(data = X_test)

# Calculating feature importance
final_score = []
shuff_pred = []
for i,col in enumerate(X_test):

    # shuffle column
    shuff_test = X_test.copy()
    shuff_test[:,i] = np.random.permutation(shuff_test[:,i])
    
    # compute score
    score = mean_absolute_error(y_test, reverse_target(y_test.ravel(), y_train.mean().values, y_train.std().values))
    shuff_pred.append(reverse_target(y_test.ravel(), y_train.mean().values, y_train.std().values))
    final_score.append(score)
    
final_score = np.asarray(final_score)
```

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-347c293a47c8>", line 22, in <module>
    shuff_test[:,i] = np.random.permutation(shuff_test[:,i])

  File "C:\Users\hanif\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\Users\hanif\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 353, in get_loc
    return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

  File "C:\Users\hanif\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 116, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key
```

Comment: If you want to access a Pandas dataframe by row and column indices, use `.iloc` (e.g. `shuff_test.iloc[:,i] = np.random.permutation(shuff_test.iloc[:,i])`).

Comment: I've changed the line, but I get another error when executing `score = mean_absolute_error(y_test, reverse_target(y_test.ravel(), y_train.mean().values, y_train.std().values))`. `AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'values'`